# How to list device options in ffmpeg with its avdevice C++ API?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

How to list all available device("dshow and v422 source for example") options(formats/resolutions/fps) and chose the preffered one from the C++ API?

I know that it is possible using CLI

`ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="Integrated Camera"`

But how to use it into my C++ application?

I tryed to find some useful fields inside the `AVDeviceInfoList` struct, but it doesn`t contains any options list.

```
  AVDeviceInfoList* deviceList;
           int deviceCount = avdevice_list_input_sources(inFormat, nullptr, nullptr, &deviceList);



           for(int i = 0; i<deviceList->nb_devices;++i){
               qDebug()<<deviceList->devices[i]->device_name;
               qDebug()<<deviceList->devices[i]->media_types[0];
               qDebug()<<deviceList->devices[i]->device_description;

           }`
```